# Moving the SecondaryName Node in a Cloudera HBase Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I deployed the secondary namenode on the same machine is my main namenode:

[image]

This is *wrong* for performance and durability reasons (the secondary name node isn't a hot spare, but it does have a copy of needed metadata). I have found [documentation on how to move the namenode](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/archives/cloudera-manager-4/v4-5-4/Cloudera-Manager-Enterprise-Edition-User-Guide/cmeeug_topic_5_17.html), but nothing about moving the secondary namenode.

Does anyone with experience know how to do this safely?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just remove the Secondary role and then add it back again on a different host? You will be temporarily without a secondary namenode, but that shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: @growse: No idea - if I could answer that I wouldn't be asking random people on the internet how to manage my HBase cluster ;-)

Comment: I therefore offer you an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It should be safe enough to simply remove the Secondary Namenode role, and then add it back again onto a different node on the cluster. In the intermediate period, you may see a warning from Cloudera Manager that the role doesn't exist (which may cause long term issues with the namenode), but not having a Secondary doesn't put your data any more at risk.

Answer (score 3):

The job of the 2NN is to read the changes on the HDFS filesystem and add them to the `fsimage`. This decreases NN startup time as during startup the NN reads the `fsimage` file and then applies all the interim log changes on top of it. The naming is somewhat unfortunate as it is indeed not a standby/backup NN but only a utility to increase NN performance.

- In CM there's an option to "Roll Edits" (depending on your CM version) on the 2NN, see also ["Checkpointing"](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/03/a-guide-to-checkpointing-in-hadoop/). Make sure to do that before moving.
- To be safe stop all services
- Move the 2NN role to a new machine.
- Restart all services
- (Optional but worth it): Implement HA